# Complexity of BPR (Bayesian Personalized Ranking)

Tags: bayesian, gradient-descent, recommender-system

I am using lightFM framework and it uses BPR as logistic loss. When looking at the paper that describes [BPR](http://www.algo.uni-konstanz.de/members/rendle/pdf/Rendle_et_al2009-Bayesian_Personalized_Ranking.pdf), it says that it takes m · |S| single update steps until convergence. However, the complexity of every step is not described. Moreover in order to know when the SGD converges, the algorithm needs to compute the BPR loss function at every step too and this seems to be a massive computation.

[image: algorithm description]

I am interested in the matrix factorization modelization of the problem. If anyone has an idea of how I can tackle this problem, I would really appreciate.

Comment: I have some experience using BPR, however I can't figure out what exactly your question is...